# A running number column incrementing its value by conditon

Tags: sql

Is there a way to create a column with a running number that would increment its value by 1 whenever a value in another column has a specific value? For example, if we have

```
  colA 
    a 
    c 
change 
    b 
    c 
    b 
change 
    b 
    a 
    . 
    . 
    .
```

then I would like to have

```
colA          colB 
    a           1 
    c           1 
change          2 
    b           2 
    c           2 
    b           2 
change          3
    b           3 
    a           3 
    .           . 
    .           . 
    .           .
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Is there an id column too, or similar?

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the below solutions assume that you have some explicit `orderCriteria` by which you're ordering your events.

#### Here's how you'd do it with PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
SELECT
  colA,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE colA = 'change') OVER (ORDER BY orderCriteria) + 1 colB,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY orderCriteria
```

#### Here's how you'd do it with any other RDBMS supporting window functions:

(these include CUBRID, DB2, Firebird 3, HANA, Informix, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Redshift, SQL Server, Sybase SQL Anywhere, and others)

```
SELECT
  colA,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN colA = 'change' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY orderCriteria) + 1 colB,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY orderCriteria
```

#### Here's how you'd do it with any other RDBMS:

```
SELECT
  colA,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM my_table t2
   WHERE t2.orderCriteria <= t1.orderCriteria
   AND t2.colA = 'change') + 1 colB
FROM my_table t1
ORDER BY orderCriteria
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified how you want to order so i will use an `idColumn`:

```
SELECT colA,
       colB = (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName t2
               WHERE   colA = 'change'
               AND     t2.idColumn <= t.idColumn) + 1
FROM dbo.TableName t      
ORDER BY idColumn
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d054/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: `colB = (SELECT ...)`  is invalid (standard) SQL. You can't do an assignment like that inside a SELECT statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you're right, since OP didnt specify his or her rdbms i have used T-SQL. However, the approach works in any database, you just have to change it a little bit.